# Merging pdf with pdfsharp : exception en the pdfDocument.close()

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfsharp

I would like to create a function with PDFSharp in order to merge some pdf's.

Here is my code

```
public class PDF_Merge
{
    static string [] strTabPdfFiles;


    public static string SetPdfToMerge(string strPdfFilesInput)
    {
        strTabPdfFiles = strPdfFilesInput.Split(';');
        return "O";
    }

    public static string MergeToPdf(string strPdfFilesOutput)
    {
        try
        {
            PdfDocument objDocumentFinal = new PdfDocument(strPdfFilesOutput);

            foreach (string strDoc in strTabPdfFiles)
            {
                PdfDocument objDocument = PdfReader.Open(strDoc, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

                foreach (PdfPage page in objDocument.Pages)
                {
                    objDocumentFinal.AddPage(page);
                }
                objDocument.Close();----------> Exception : File cannot be modified
            }
            objDocumentFinal.Close();

            objDocumentFinal.Save(strPdfFilesOutput);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }

        return "O";
    }

}
```

My problem is that on the objDocument.Close() call, i have an exception : "The document cannot be modified".

Anyone could help me about that ?

Great thanks for this lib,

Best regards,

Nixeus

Answer (score 7):

`PdfDocument.Close` should only be called for documents created with a filename or a stream. `Close` will then automatically save the contents to the PDF file. You must not call `Save` in this case.

With the sample code in the question, `Close` must not be called for `objDocument` because it was not modified and cannot be saved.
It's OK to call `Close` for `objDocumentFinal` to save the changes. You should not call `Save` for `objDocumentFinal` because this will only save the changes again.

A PDF file opened with PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import is for import only and cannot be modified.
Try PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify instead.

Look at the Concatenate Documents sample:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/ConcatenateDocuments-sample.ashx

Comment: I don't want to modify any pdf ! If you look on my code, you can see that i create a new pdf. So, the import mode should be ok, no?

Comment: Can you guys add this to the error message someday. It's completely un-self-explanatory right now. Even `CanSave` returns true but you still get the error.

Answer (score 4):

I know I am late to the party, but I encountered this issue today.

The close method is trying to save the document, and thus the requirement for `.Modify`. In this case you don't need `objDocument.Close()` at all. You can optionally (and probably should?) call `objDocument.Dispose()`.

Comment: Late to the party too.  But this is really poor coding of the Pdf-Sharp team.  Close or dispose either of these should act as everything else and should actually release the file from the OS.  Right after a call to Close I too get the exception and a call to dispose I still cannot delete the old file.